# Looping a process in C#

Tags: c#, exception, loops

I'm familiar with loops, yet looping a process has left me bewildered:

If the user enters a *non-integer*, I would like the question 'your age' to be prompted again until the user enters an *integer*.

```
 Console.WriteLine("Your age:");
 string line = Console.ReadLine();
 if (!int.TryParse(line, out age))
 {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} is not an integer", line);

 }
```

Comment: I think you can use recursive functions for this.

Comment: @venkateshwar: Really? So a thousand or two bad ints crashes your program with an unrecoverable stackoverflow exception? Recursion should be avoided if the depth of the recursion is potentially unbounded... as is the case here.

Comment: @spender Ya i got [lesson](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12550746/1577396) for that. I will avoid using this in future.:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, it will make *"Your age: "* repeat until you have correct input:

```
int age;
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your age:");
    string line = Console.ReadLine();

    if (!int.TryParse(line, out age))
       Console.WriteLine("{0} is not an integer", line);

    else break;
}
```

Comment: ...it commands the MSIL compiler to pass the value as reference i.e. to store the value at a supplied address by the caller function. In this case for a 32bit integer, a `stind.i4` operation is added...

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
int age;

Console.WriteLine("Your age:");
string line = Console.ReadLine();
while (!int.TryParse(line, out age))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not an integer", line);
    Console.WriteLine("Your age:");
    line = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I'm not sure what you mean by *looping a process*.  You are looping around getting user input and attempting to parse that input.

You can principally accomplish that using *while*, *do*, *for*, or (gulp!  don't do it!) *goto*.

Comment: Nitpicking a little, but he wants "Your age:" to be displayed again if you enter a non integer, so you may want to add that.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this approach. I dont know whether this will decrease the performance or not but I find it cool to use regex. Let me know if this works out for ya

Add this to the TOP

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Then use the following :

```
            bool bEnteredNumberNotValid = true;
            while (bEnteredNumberNotValid)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your age:");
                string sAge = Console.ReadLine();

                string regString = "(^[0-9]+$)"; //REGEX FOR ONLY NUMBERS

                Regex regVal = new Regex(regString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline); //REGEX ENGINE
                Match matVal = regVal.Match(sAge); //REGEX MATCH WITH THE INPUT
                if (!matVal.Success) // IF THERE IS NO MATCH, SHOW THE BELOW
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not an integer", sAge);
                }
                else // ELSE SET bEnteredNumberNotValid FALSE AND GET OUT.
                {
                    bEnteredNumberNotValid = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
```

OUTPUT!

[Click here to see the output of above program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3bC5.png)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well your question, why don't you just do

```
Console.WriteLine("Your age:");
string line = Console.ReadLine();
while (!int.TryParse(line, out age))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not an integer", line);
    Console.WriteLine("Your age:");
    line = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know only Recursive Function to achieve this but it is not recommended because it is error prone and makes the program overly complicated.

**In class**

```
 string line;
 int age = 0;
```

**In Main**

```
 Console.WriteLine("Your age:");   
 line  = Console.ReadLine();  
 checkFunction();
```

**Declare a method**

```
public int checkFunction()
{
  if (!int.TryParse(line, out age))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not an integer", line);
    line = Console.ReadLine();
    return checkFunction();
  }
  else
  {
    return age;
  }
}
```

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use recursion to solve this problem. In fact recursion makes it overly complicated and error prone.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that you cannot guarantee that it will terminate properly. The user might not enter a number at all and doing so too many times will result in a stack overflow due to the recursion which will fill the stack. Unlikely yes but still a possibility.